# Получить все элементы кроме текущего jQuery

Tags: jquery

У нас есть 5 дивов с классом class

```
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
```

Задаю всем тегам одинаковый текст по события клик:

```
$('body').on('click', '.class', function () {

   $('.class').html('fjenekn');
    
});
```

Как можно обойти стороной текущий элемент, на который я кликнул, чтобы не применять к нему изменения?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод **[not](https://api.jquery.com/not/)**

```js
$('body').on('click', '.class', function () {
   $('.class').not($(this)).html('fjenekn');        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class">1</div>
<div class="class">2</div>
<div class="class">3</div>
<div class="class">4</div>
```

Comment: Можно просто `this`

Answer (score 0):

Оставлю такой же вариант но на JS

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.class');

[].forEach.call(items, function(e,i,items) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.clear();
    [].forEach.call(items, function(e) {
      if(e !== this) {
        console.info(e.innerText);
      }
    }, this);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="class">1</div>
<div class="class">2</div>
<div class="class">3</div>
<div class="class">4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о соседних дивах, то просто `siblings()`

```js
$(".class").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().html('txt');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class">1</div>
<div class="class">2</div>
<div class="class">3</div>
<div class="class">4</div>
```